# C# Webclient Download from ASP.NET Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, download, webclient

I'm having a bit of fun with ASP.NET, WinForms and the WebClient. So I'm using my ASP.NET application as my back end communications for my desktop application and I have had success returning simple string/integer values from the controllers after sending data to them but when I tried to get complex and return entire objects as files, the content returns blank (but it does show the custom content type in the response). Here is my code below, am I doing something wrong? (First time messing with the webclient like this :))

Controller

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpGet]
public APIRegister(....)
{
   // ..... Create User Account / etc .....
   return File(Methods.Conversions.ObjectToArray(SomeData), "application/custom");
}
```

The "ObjectToArray" method simply converts the object to a byte array.

Client

```
HttpWebRequest WR = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(MyUrl/Account/APIRegister?Params...);
byte[] RawResponse = new byte[0];
using (HttpWebResponse WD = (HttpWebResponse)WR.GetResponse())
{
    Stream SR = WD.GetResponseStream();
    RawResponse = Methods.Conversions.StreamToArray(SR);
}
```

The content always returns a length of zero but it does keep the content header type of "application/custom" so it is returning that just not the actual content itself. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It is totally unclear how Methods.Conversions.StreamToArray works and by the looks of it I doubt it ever gets hold of the Stream that is assigned to SR.

Comment: Edited to include that the Stream is passed to the method but i don't believe that matters anyways considering the content length of the response itself it 0 so no data is being returned from the controller other than the content type of "application/custom".

Comment: Why you want to return file instead of the data .You CA. Return data in json format and deserialize it to object in Windows application.

Comment: Returning the file in a JSON format doesn't always work nicely with images/large files so I'm trying to devise a way to handle all of the scenarios I will need.

Comment: Images and files are completely different things then objects. You really should separate the two cases, json is there for a reason, returning objects serialized as a byte array not only is inefficient but also destroys the concept of interoperability completely.

Comment: Well that is kind of what I'm asking is for some help with how to do this correctly instead of everyone just telling me I'm doing it wrong...

Comment: Are you saying your success with simple string/integers is using the same APIRegister controller?

Comment: Sorry that one is my fault, I've had success using Chetan's method of json requests with integer/string values but no go with images (tried converting to BASE64 but that opens up other problems like image size, etc ;)). I suppose maybe I should stick with the JSON method for smaller bits of data and use an HTTP post method like the above with simple HTTP responses instead (since all I need is validation that it was uploaded, not the actual returned data).

Comment: Although, that would lead me to question, would this be the proper way to do it for image/file downloads that are byte arrays (uploaded via the file.readallbytes on the client side) other than changing the content to "image/png", etc?

Comment: May you be more specific on your use case? Do you want to return both serialized data *and* images in the same response? Or are you talking about two different action methods which will return different things?

Comment: Simply just the file data (file bytes that were uploaded), say a PDF that was uploaded from the client and that client used "File.ReadAllBytes()" to get the bytes of the file before uploading it. Would "File(SomeFileBytes, "document/pdf")" be the correct way to return that?

Comment: In that scenario yes, it's the correct way.

Comment: I think I'm good then, just need some clarification I think :). Will post again if the other specific scenario doesn't work as it's sort of unrelated. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Per Federico's comments, decided it was better/more feasible to attempt to separate the "small" data into JSON requests versus using a HTTP GET file method.